# innerHTML not outputting anything

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am new to the whole OOP JavaScript style of writing code, so I am trying to learn it to go with the trend.

I wrote a simple function, where I am trying to take advantage of prototypes and  `this`. Looks followingly:

```
function Person(name, age, height, weight, IQ, ethnicity){
    this.fullName = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.IQ = IQ;
    this.ethnicity = ethnicity;
}

let Jou = new Person("Joseph", 21, 191, 78, 131, "caucasian");
let Franc = new Person("Francois", 13, 178, 50, 125, "caucasian");
let Svata = new Person("Svatopluk", 61, 188, 85, 140, "caucasian");

let names= ["Jou", "Franc", "Svata"];
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < names.lenght; i++){
        text += names[i].fullName + " is " + names[i].age + " years old, " 
             + names[i].height + "cm tall, weighs approximately " 
             + names[i].weight + "kg, his IQ is around " + names[i].IQ + 
             " and he belongs to the " + names[i].ethnicity.toUpperCase() + 
             " ethnicity." + "<br>" ;
}

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;
```

I am inserting it into: `<p id="name"></p>`

Could anyone give me some pointers, on what I am missing, so I can learn how to work with it?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Further to the posted answers I'll point out the typo: `names.lenght`

Answer (score 2):

The `names` array contains strings, not the actual variables. You should remove the double quotes. Also, `names.lenght` should be `names.length`.

```js
function Person(name, age, height, weight, IQ, ethnicity){
    this.fullName = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.IQ = IQ;
    this.ethnicity = ethnicity;
}

let Jou = new Person("Joseph", 21, 191, 78, 131, "caucasian");
let Franc = new Person("Francois", 13, 178, 50, 125, "caucasian");
let Svata = new Person("Svatopluk", 61, 188, 85, 140, "caucasian");

let names= [Jou, Franc, Svata];
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        text += names[i].fullName + " is " + names[i].age + " years old, " 
             + names[i].height + "cm tall, weighs approximately " 
             + names[i].weight + "kg, his IQ is around " + names[i].IQ + 
             " and he belongs to the " + names[i].ethnicity.toUpperCase() + 
             " ethnicity." + "<br>" ;
}
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've enclosed variable names in strings, whereas you should reference them as variables, not strings, so change this:

```
let names= ["Jou", "Franc", "Svata"];
```

to this:

```
let names= [Jou, Franc, Svata];
```

Besides, you have a typo, that's why your original `let names= [Jou, Franc, Svata];` didn't work, so change

```
names.lenght
         ^^^
```

to

```
names.length
         ^^^
```